# Returning rows with same ID after a specific status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

**I will put this down as best I can. I know you help when you also understand the question :)**

I have a column with different ApplicationStatus with the same ApplicationID. When the ApplicationStatus reaches 'Audit Complete' the first time and there was any activity AFTER that then it should return those ApplicationStatuses (Even if 'Audit Complete' appears again after the 'Audit Complete' ApplicationStatus again. Then when 'Audit Complete' does not appear in the group of ApplicationID's then it should also not return those rows.

**[My Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZqYn.png)**

**This is what I would like to return** (The other columns don't have any problems):

```
            ApplicationID | Application Status
          ----------------|--------------------
               926521     | Submitted to Bank
               926521     | Audit Complete
```

The first 'Audit Complete' ApplicationStatus could appear in any row of the ApplicationID group.

**Here is the code I have tried** (Let me know if you want me to shorten the code(I just wanted to show you what I have tried):

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT 
        status.ApplicationID AS [Application ID],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY status.ApplicationID ORDER BY status.ApplicationID) AS [Row Number],
        status.ApplicationStatusMovementID AS [Application Status Movement ID], 
        status.ApplicationStatus AS [Application Status],
        status.Comment, 
        status.CreatedDate AS [Created Date],
        app.BondFacilitator AS [Bond Facilitator],

        CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY status.ApplicationID) > 3 AND status.ApplicationStatus IN ('Audit Complete') --OR COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY status.ApplicationID) > 3
        THEN 'NO'
        WHEN COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY status.ApplicationID) > 3 AND status.ApplicationStatus NOT IN ('Audit Complete') --OR COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY status.ApplicationID) > 3
        THEN 'FINE'
        ELSE 'FINE'
        END AS [Status]

FROM Import.OobaApplicationStatusMovement AS status

LEFT OUTER JOIN Import.OobaApplication  AS app ON status.ApplicationID = app.ApplicationID

GROUP BY 
        status.ApplicationID,
        ApplicationStatusMovementID, 
        status.ApplicationStatus, 
        Comment, 
        status.CreatedDate,
        BondFacilitator

)
SELECT  [Application ID],
        [Row Number],
        [Application Status Movement ID], 
        [Application Status],
        Comment,
        [Created Date],
        [Bond Facilitator],
        [Status],

        IIF(COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [Application ID]) > COUNT([Status]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Application ID], [Status]), 'NO', 'YES') AS [Activity After Audit Completed]


FROM (
    SELECT [Application ID],
        [Row Number],
        [Application Status Movement ID], 
        [Application Status],
        Comment,
        [Created Date],
        [Bond Facilitator],
        [Status],

        IIF(COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [Application ID]) > COUNT([Status]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Application ID], [Status]), 'NO', 'YES') AS [Activity After Audit Completed]


FROM CTE) AS result

WHERE  [Row Number] IN
    (SELECT [Row Number] + i
    FROM CTE
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 2 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 15) AS n
WHERE [Application Status] = 'Audit Complete') AND [Activity After Audit Completed] IN ('NO') AND Status IN ('FINE', 'NO')


ORDER BY [Application ID], [Created Date]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I miss something or didn't get your question right, but I guess the solution is pretty simple. Please find following an example. First I define a table with a few example records, then I perform the select in order to show all statuses where "Audit Complete" is not the last status:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Application_ID int, RowNumber int, ApplStatus nvarchar(50));

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (926521, 1, 'Work in Progress'), (926521, 2, 'Submitted to Bank'), (926521, 3, 'Audit Complete'),
                      (926521, 4, 'Submitted to Bank'), (926521, 5, 'Audit Complete');

INSERT INTO @t VALUES (933633, 1, 'Work in Progress'), (933633, 2, 'Submitted to Bank'), (933633, 3, 'Cancelled'),
                      (933633, 4, 'Submitted to Bank'), (933633, 5, 'Audit Complete');

WITH cteRows AS(
  SELECT Application_ID
        ,ApplStatus
        ,MIN(RowNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY Application_ID, ApplStatus) rnMinStatus
        ,MAX(RowNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY Application_ID) rnMax
    FROM @t
),
cteFiltered AS(
  SELECT *
    FROM cteRows
    WHERE ApplStatus = 'Audit Complete'
      AND rnMinStatus < rnMax
)
SELECT DISTINCT a.Application_ID, a.ApplStatus
  FROM @t AS a
  JOIN cteFiltered AS b ON a.Application_ID = b.Application_ID
  WHERE a.RowNumber > b.rnMinStatus
```

Comment: You are welcome. Glad I could help. It would be nice of you if you could accept my answer.